# Search for Arabic word in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with an Arabic column which may contains variant forms of the same word in multiple rows, for example the word " القوم" might be in the following forms:

الْقَوْمِ
الْقَوْمُ
الْقَوْمَ
القوم

I tried to execute this query:

```sql
select * 
from TestTable 
where ArabicChars like '%القوم%'
```

The result is:

```
ArabicChars ar_id
القوم                    4
```

But I want the result to be the four rows.

I'm looking for a way to store these values in the database (actually I need a solution for SQL Server), and to retrieve them regardless of these differences.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What collation do you have set for your database?

Comment: select * from TestTable where ArabicChars like N'%القوم%'

Answer (score 1):

The closest feature to this in SQL Server is fulltext indexing, and Arabic is one of the supported languages [SQL Server fulltext language support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-fulltext-languages-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).  You'd need to set your collation to the right setting to get this to work for your database, but hopefully this will solve your problem.

Comment: the current database collation is Arabic_CI_AI and I  tried the fulltext indexing on the table but still have the same result

Comment: I don't speak Arabic, so I can't tell you much about the specific examples you put in your post.  However, you can look into what the index has using the DMVs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-fts-index-keywords-by-property-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current) and see if the "stem" values match up with what you are trying to search.  Note that LIKE won't work for this - you need to use the fulltext verbs (CONTAINS or similar) to do a search using the index.